# Direct link to specific answers

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, answers, hyperlinks

Would it be a good idea to have the capability to directly link to a specific answer?  Sometimes when answering questions, I would like to link to another questions's answer, but it isn't always the accepted answer.

A good example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671/is-it-safe-for-structs-to-implement-interfaces).  The accepted answer has been up-voted, but there is another answer that goes into much more detail (and has a lot more up-votes).  It seems that the more up-voted answer has been more helpful to people visiting the question after the initial accepted answer.

So, when answering another question, it might be nice to reference just the more detailed answer.  In this context, it wouldn't be correct to name the new question as duplicate because the context of the question is different.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/63757/99456)?

Comment: Look for the "Share" link on each answer.

Comment: Ah, yes... :) How did you generate that link?

Comment: Upvoted, because it does not appear this question has been asked before, and I can see how the "Share" link might be automatically assumed to be a Social Networking 'share' thing. That said, I'm pretty sure the down votes are because the Share link seems obvious to most users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This already exists, there's a "share" link under each post (question or answer) that produces a direct link to the post.

[image]

You can also get direct links to comments by clicking on their timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

Under every answer and question there is a share button. Clicking on it will reveal the sharing URL.

On a related note, clicking on the time a comment was posted will point your browser to that specific comment