# Linking to a Specific Comment

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190286/rolling-back-approved-edits).

And wanted to provide a link to a comment. I can find a solution to provide a [link to a specific answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174991/direct-link-to-specific-answers).

Apart from going to the user's profile and their activity, finding the comment and obtaining a link from there,

I there an easier way to a specific comment?

Comment: @Cody nice find, never noticed that one! Thought it's one of the undocumented features. :)

Comment: @CodyGray I swear to god I searched it.. as I found the links to specific answers. holy cr@p..

Comment: Don't feel bad. Meta is a strange place and sometimes things are hard to find. My voting to close isn't a comment on your unwillingness or inability to search.

Comment: @CodyGray No I understand that, I just hate it when such an obvious duplicate is found., I will delete this comment after u see it, just  not necessary if u know what I mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, the comment time stamp is a link:

> [image]

When in doubt, hover! :)

Comment: "When in doubt, hover!" ... now there's something that should go on a t-shirt...

Comment: I didin't realise.. OMG>...and it works beautifully, yes hover, if in doubt hover.. thnx (I feel like a blooming idiot - not a regular idiot - one in bloom - but that's for English Exchange ;)

Comment: *"When in doubt, hover!"* Hmm, that's exactly what I do at parties, but people say I'm creepy.

Comment: @CodyGray I avoid large groups of people LOL

Comment: @Skippy didn't get notifications on this post for some reason checked now just by chance... glad I made you bloom! :-P

Comment: @Bart go ahead, I'll buy the shirt!

Comment: @Cody they obviously didn't read the Hitchhiker's Guide then! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, click the 'Date' stamp against the comment and you'll get the anchor link for that comment that you can use.

For example - [Reduce close vote expiration restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190148/reduce-close-vote-expiration-restrictions#comment588747_190148)

Comment: thanks Jon, yes, it there and working perfectly... doh